# Спарсить строку с байтами в массив байт (Java)

Tags: java, массивы, строки

Есть массив байт

```
byte[] byteArray = {1, 22, 44, 55};
```

Мы сделали его строковое представление через

```
 Arrays.toString(byteArray);
```

Получилась строка `"[1, 22, 44, 55]"`.
Как из этой строки обратно спарсить массив этих байт, то есть:

```
byte[] byteArray = {1, 22, 44, 55};
```

Answer (score 1):

Сначала заменяем символы `[` и `]`, а затем делим строку на числа через `,` . Потом проходимся по каждому этому числу и парсим из него значение с помощью `Byte.parseByte`.

```
byte[] byteArray = {1, 127, 44, 55};
String s = Arrays.toString(byteArray).replaceAll("([\\[\\]])", "");

String[] arrStr = s.split(", ");
byte[] arr = new byte[arrStr.length];
for (int i = 0; i < arrStr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = Byte.parseByte(arrStr[i]);
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```